# How to give meaningful Ω and Big-O bounds for this function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Can someone please explain this for me I don't quite understand how to solve this. I need to give meaningful Ω and Big-O bounds for this function and be able to justify it.

```
bool algo1(int a[], int n){
    if ((n < 1) || (a[0] % 2 == 0))
         return true;
    int z = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)
         for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
         z += a[j];
    return (z % 2 == 0);
}

int algo2(int n){
    if (n == 0)
           return 1;
    return algo2(n-1) + algo2(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`algo1` has `for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)` which is logarithmic on `n` (divide by half repeatedly). For each of those `log(n)` iterations we have `for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)` which is linear on `n`. Everything else is constant time. Multiplying the outer and inner loops gives O(n log(n)).

`algo2` is exponential time, O(2<sup>n</sup>), because on every call frame, it spawns two recursive calls that each count down by a linear factor on `n`.

For both algorithms, the complexity bounds don't vary, so theta, omega and big o are the same.

Answer (score 0):

For program 2, there is another way to derive the time complexity

```
int algo2(int n){
    if (n == 0)
           return 1;
    return algo2(n-1) + algo2(n-1);
}
```

In base case it take constant time.

In inductive case problem is divided into 2 parts and problem size is reduced from n to n-1 in each step.

Hence we can represent the recurrence relation,

```
T(n) = T(n-1) +T(n-1) + 1

=> T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1

The above recurrence is in form of Master theorem(for subtract and conquer recurrences):

T(n) = aT(n-b) +f(n) , for some constants c, a > 0, b > 0, d ≥ 0, and function f(n).

For equation,
T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1

a=2, b=1

O(n^d) = 1
=> O(n^0) =1
=>d=0

As a>1 thus the above recurrence fall under case 3 of Master theorem(for subtract and conquer recurrences)

Thus T(n) = O(n^d a^n/b)

Substituting value of a,b and d in above equation, we have

=>T(n) = O(n^0 2^n/1)
=>T(n) = O(2^n)
```

Thus the time complexity T(n) = 2^n

Answer (score -1):

the time complexity of the above program is O(nlog(n))

Because the first  for loop is looping for n/2 times so the first loop will have log(n) complexity

second for loop looping n times so it will have (n)

In general, doing something with every item in one dimension is linear, doing something with every item in two dimensions is quadratic, and dividing the working area in half is logarithmic.

Comment: There are 2 programs, for more clarity please mention about the program you are talking about. Otherwise it may create confusion.